# PHP: PDO select query does not return record that is in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am running this PDO query:

```
$sql['check_for_existing_rates'] = 'SELECT * FROM rates_table where '
                                        . 'listing_id = :listing_id AND '
                                        . 'start_date = :start_date AND '
                                        . 'end_date = :end_date';
```

[EDIT]
So for example, i check to see if the dates in the summer array are present in the rates_table for a specific listing_id:

`SELECT * FROM rates_table where start_date = '2015-04-15' AND end_date= '2014-12-14' AND listing_id = 1`;

[EDIT]
I query the rates_table by start_date, end_date, and listing_id because a listing can and does have multiple rates, with the rate_id being the primary key.  If there is a defined rate for a specific start_date/end_date span then i don't want that rate to be updated.

[EDIT]

```
foreach($rates as rate){
    //use the agent_listing_id to get my listing_id

    foreach($rates['agent_rate_data'] as $rate_array){
        $stmt = $db->query($sql['check_for_existing_rates'],array('listing_id'=>$listing_id,
        'start_date'=>$rate_array['start_date'],
        'end_date'=>$rate_array['end_date'])); 

        if(!$stmt->fetchAll()){
            //Insert a record
        }else{
            //log that the record already exist and move onto the next rate period
        }
        }   //end foreach rate_array

}//end foreach $rates
```

I check if there is a result returned for the dates int the select query and then based on that result either do nothing or insert a DB record.

This is is the Query Function:

```
function query($sql,$input_parameters = null, &$insert_id = null){
        $pdo = $this->getPDO();
        $insert_id = null;
        if(is_null($input_parameters)){
            $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
            //echo $sql;
        }else{
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            //echo $sql;
            //var_dump($input_parameters);
            $stmt->execute($input_parameters);
        }
        if(stripos($sql,'insert')=== 0){
            $insert_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        }
        return $stmt;
    }
```

Rates is an array of rate arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [agent_villa_title] => Lovely Villa
    [agent_villa_id] => 1234
    [agent_villa_currency] => USD
    [agent_rate_data] => Array
        (
            [summer] => Array
                (
                    [title_1] => Summer 2015
                    [start_date] => 2015-04-15
                    [end_date] => 2015-12-14
                    [nightly_rate] => 400
                    [nightly_rate_weekend] => 400
                    [weekly_rate] => 2800
                    [ctime] => 2015-10-28 14:18:28
                    [mtime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [active] => 1
                    [min_stay] => 5
                    [updated_by_feed] => 1
                )

            [winter_0] => Array
                (
                    [title_1] => Winter 2016
                    [start_date] => 2015-12-15
                    [end_date] => 2015-12-19
                    [nightly_rate] => 600
                    [nightly_rate_weekend] => 600
                    [weekly_rate] => 4200
                    [ctime] => 2015-10-28 14:18:28
                    [mtime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [active] => 1
                    [min_stay] => 7
                    [updated_by_feed] => 1
                )

            [christmas] => Array
                (
                    [title_1] => Christmas and New Year 2016
                    [start_date] => 2015-12-20
                    [end_date] => 2016-01-10
                    [nightly_rate] => 0
                    [nightly_rate_weekend] => 0
                    [weekly_rate] => 0
                    [ctime] => 2015-10-28 14:18:28
                    [mtime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [active] => 1
                    [min_stay] => 14
                    [updated_by_feed] => 1
                )

            [winter_1] => Array
                (
                    [title_1] => Winter 2016
                    [start_date] => 2016-01-11
                    [end_date] => 2016-04-14
                    [nightly_rate] => 600
                    [nightly_rate_weekend] => 600
                    [weekly_rate] => 4200
                    [ctime] => 2015-10-28 14:18:28
                    [mtime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [active] => 1
                    [min_stay] => 7
                    [updated_by_feed] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

The db query above always return an empty result array for the [summer] element.

- The start and end date for each element are always the same.
- The query finds the summer records when i run it manually in the database for the summer dates.
- If i reorder the $rates array so that [summer] is not the first element; the query still returns an empty array for [summer].

It's wrecking my head.
Any suggestions?
Cheers

Comment: Pls provide us with sample data and the exact query you tried to run. Pls be mindful that the dates are not the only selection criteria you have, you also have a listing_id.

Comment: and **$listing_id** comes from .... ?

Comment: ^ Which is confusing. Why add the dates to the query if you're passing the ID? They all have the same dates anyway, as you've said?

Comment: Just a guess probably you mean :  `foreach($rates as $listing_id=>$rate_array){`

Comment: What is the result of the SQL query when you run it directly in mysql?

Comment: Start by narrowing it down to a concrete SQL query which you run directly on your database using phpmyadmin or the mysql command line client or whatever else. This is all about the database, the data it contains and your concrete query. Too much code, too little concrete values.

Comment: Hi.  Firstly; Thank you all for responding.  @Shadow: I edited the code to show an exact query that i'm running.

Comment: @Alex: The listing id used is retrieved from my listing_table using the agent_listing_id(unique to each listing in that table).

Comment: @Mikel.  I edited the question above to describe why i use the start and end dates in the query.

Comment: @Ian:  When i run the query in my database it returns all of the information for the appropriate record; so rate_id, nightly_rate, etc. The query works when i run it directly on the database with PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems with your post.

First: It's not obvious what your issue is. What in particular isn't working as expected? Is there a function call that isn't returning what you want?

Also, this jumps out at me as being a bit strange:

```
if(!$stmt->fetchAll()){
    //Insert a record
}else{
    //log that the record already exist and move onto the next rate period
}
```

It's not clear what you're doing inside these conditionals. Once you run `$stmt->fetchAll()`, the dataset has been fetched, you cannot fetch it a second time. Generally speaking, unless you're actually going to use the results of `fetchAll()`, you should opt for a different way to see if any results exist.

Comment: Hi Ian.  Thanks for answering.  It's my first post and i can see that i need to work on my clarity. My issue was that i when i was checking my db for records that i knew to be there i was consistently getting an empty result for one of the queried date spans.  I fixed it.  I was running a query(should've put it in my post) before the foreach($rate['agent_rate_array']) that was deleting future rates not marked as being updated by feed and my where clause was incorrectly deleting the rates .  I'm not using the fetchall() results: can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Well, if all you want to do is check if a row exists, you should change the SQL query to reflect that. Do something more like this `$pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x')->fetchColumn();` which minimizes the amount of data being fetched/processed.

Comment: As for your question above, next time, you should try to be very specific in what you're asking or needing help with. Don't clutter your question with tons of random tid-bits, and don't be afraid to go back and correct mistakes. You can add/remove from anywhere in the post, so don't feel the need to always append new info, instead go back and correct what was wrong.